# jquery random image issue

Tags: jquery, image, random

I am trying to load 1 of 2 images at random on load of my home page. (ico.edu) - Currently, only 1 image loads (I want the 2nd image to load "randomly") - so sometimes users get to my website and image 1 loads, other times it's image 2. So far, *only* image 1 loads.

Here is the jQuery inside my php page that should load the random image, but nothing I change in the code seems to work. Help? (PS - this website is built with WordPress so this is custom code added to the WordPress homepage.php in order to customize the theme used....

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);    
var randimg;

if (number === 1) {
    randimg  = "http://www.ico.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/home_slides-students-guy2.jpg";
} else { randimg  = "http://www.ico.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/home_slides-students-duo.jpg"; }


$('img').
filter(function() {
    return this.src.match("http://www.ico.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/home_slides-students-guy2.jpg"); //if image caching is off
    //return this.src.match("http://i0.wp.com/www.ico.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/home_slides-students-guy.jpg"); //with image caching version
})
.attr("src", randimg);

});
</script>
```

Comment: verify if your code is executed by adding a console log, i guess it has to do sth. with that filter, why not leave the src initially blank and have a better identifiing selector for that img tag?

Comment: i verified the code is in fact "reading" per my inspector. also, i commented out the filter all together and still, the function isn't pulling the "else" image. Is it because my function is named `(function($)` (can't seem to find what this does) - code existed before I arrived and I'm just trying to understand what its doing, hoping that'd help me figure what's going wrong